# Add classes with JavaScript or Jquery to HTML Elements on touchscreen slide to the left or right (Mobile Screens)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm building a mobile friendly website that essentially has an events page were the user is able to see listed events in a slider container followed by the event description right underneath it. At the moment I have it functioning where the user must click the event image (As seen in the images labeled: 1 & 2) for the description to change to an event's specific description. The issue is when the user scrolls to the next event on a mobile screen, the previous event's description is still posted underneath as the user still hasn't clicked listed event #2.

Is there some sort of function or method in JavaScript or jQuery similar to:

```
var.addEventListener('click', () => { 
     
        var.classList.toggle('class');

});
```

where rather than a click, I can add or remove classes to an HTML element on a user's detected touch screen slide to the left or right? I've provided images to give you a sense of the UI on a mobile device.

[Main Display w/ Main Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0VU1.png)

[Display swiped to the left w/ description of first event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgfHE.png)

[Desired Output wanted for swipe to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75oBi.png)

Thanks! Much appreciated.
NOTE- Swiper JS is used for the Slider container.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would bind an action to the scroll event. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the info!